# Java Regex Pattern for variable date length

Tags: java, regex

**Need :** Setup a Regex pattern to extract date info which is a subset of a string.

**Issue:** The month & date is not fixed length i.e. Jan to Sep is represented by single digit & Oct - Dec with 2 digit. Also dates 1 to 9 is single digit, 10 - 31 is 2 digits

The string can be in any 1 of the below formats :

```
"CompanyUIP198710800ST" : Name YYMD nnnnn cc (i.e. CompanyUIP 1987 10800 ST)
"CompanyA1982210800ST"  : Name YYMDD nnnnn cc (i.e. CompanyA 19822 10800 ST)
"CompanyVT191039405YT"  : Name YYMMD nnnn cc (i.e. CompanyVT 19103 9405 YT)
"CompanyBX1910249405YT" : Name YYMMDD nnnn cc (i.e. CompanyBX 191024 9405 YT)
```

***In the above:***

- the first part is company name
- the next 4 or 6 digits represent the date
- the next few digits (variable length) represents identification number
- the last 2 characters is the suffix appender always 2 characters

**Pattern :** I can get Company name portion with the below regex

```
stringWord.replaceFirst("^(\\D+).*$", "$1")
```

I experimented with the below, it looks clumsy & also since I do not know the length of month or date at the begining, I will need to replace lengthDate variable with 4, 5 & 6, then remove the wrong one (i.e. more steps & clumsy).

```
int lengthDate = 4;
stringWord.substring(stringWord.replaceFirst("^(\\D+).*$", "$1").length(),
                       stringWord.replaceFirst("^(\\D+).*$", "$1").length() + lengthDate);
```

Hope the issue I face is clear & await suggestions how I can achieve it with a single regex pattern for all 4 types of date formats.

Comment: Not sure if you can distinguish all combinations of month and day, but try `^\D+(\d{2})(1[012]|[1-9])(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])\d+[A-Z]{2}$`https://regex101.com/r/Jd5bX5/1

Comment: The format is ambiguous. Is `...2019111` supposed to be `2019-11-01` or `2019-01-11`?

Comment: What is the expected match for `CompanyBX191119405YT`

Comment: In the special case cited above by both of you, if we are in the month of Oct or Nov or Dec, the next 2 digits will be assumed to be month, if not month will be assumed to be 1 digit. I know this is not a good practice, but given the string format this is the best I can think off to extract this information. Also this extraction is done once a week, so issue of legacy dates will not crop up. Any alternative suggestion is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some logic for separating the numbers, which you might want to look into your data and come up with some different expressions that would each cover part of your data, then join them using alternation.

For example, it seems to me here we have two classes:

```
^(\D+)([0-9]{4,})(9[0-9]{3})([A-Z]{2})$
```

and

```
^(\D+)([0-9]{4,})([0-9]{5})([A-Z]{2})$
```

combining them, would make it:

```
^(\D+)([0-9]{4,})(9[0-9]{3})([A-Z]{2})$|^(\D+)([0-9]{4,})([0-9]{5})([A-Z]{2})$
```

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "^(\\D+)([0-9]{4,})(9[0-9]{3})([A-Z]{2})$|^(\\D+)([0-9]{4,})([0-9]{5})([A-Z]{2})$";
        final String string = "CompanyUIP198710800ST\n"
             + "CompanyA1982210800ST\n"
             + "CompanyVT191039405YT\n"
             + "CompanyBX1910249405YT";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aNhBGS/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/aNhBGS/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thanks, agree the format is not proper. I have requested those who provide me the XML file, to ensure the date format I receive is standard. Meanwhile will try to adapt with some modif your suggestion as it does not recognize certain cases Eg: CompanyUIP19119450ST